# Changing Scene when a button is pressed Fxml

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I have 2 fxml files mainFxml.fxml and second.fxml. Main fxml has a button with fx:id="change". I want change scene when change button is clicked.
Code of mainFxml controller

```
public void onChangeButtonAction(event e){
  Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
  Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));/* Exception */
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();


}
```

but when i press button change it throws exception as no resource specified. Help me..

Stack trace

```
No resources specified.
file:/E:/Projects/javaFx/demo/dist/demo.jar!/demo/sucess.fxml:14
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:305)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:197)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:588)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2430)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2136)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2742)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2721)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2694)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2683)
  at demo.myFirstFxmlController.onSuccess(myFirstFxmlController.java:130)
  at demo.myFirstFxmlController.OnSubmitAction(myFirstFxmlController.java:53)
```

Comment: According to stacktrace, the error occurs while loading the "second.fxml" (aka sucess.fxml) at line 14. If you need help post sucess.fxml or at least lines around 14.

Comment: I made this fxml using scene builder :) I never bothered to check that file :D My mistake :(

Comment: You should post the FXML. I had some trouble loading files in my JavaFX application and one of the problems was I was referencing a controller that either didn't exist or was in another package.

Comment: Benjamin: my error was I accidentally added a space in elipsis string for a label... I never thought it'd cause a error :-) when I changed it to ... It worked:-)

Answer (score 1):

It's on the classpath so it should be the resource should be precedded with a forward slash i.e. 
    /second.fxml

That is assuming it is not in a package.  Make sure your build system is also copying it to the output directory along with your class files.

Comment: yep, second one is a common issue. If you are in Netbeans run Clean and Build to ensure that.

Comment: Its being included in the package.. I checcked using winrar..

Error exists even after changing it to /second.fxml

Comment: Is it in the root of jar is it it another directory?

Comment: There is a package with name demo and all the files are inside it

Comment: Ah, then you need /demo/second.fxml as the resource path.  Saying that, I am confused why the error message says sucess.fxml and not second.fxml.  If the above suggestion doesn't work can you post the fxml?

Answer (score 1):

"Ah, then you need /demo/second.fxml as the resource path. Saying that, I am confused why the error message says sucess.fxml and not second.fxml. If the above suggestion doesn't work can you post the fxml? – Andy Till"

This comment from Andy Till is the answer to the question.
Thanks Andy. You solved my problem :)
Thumbs up !!!

Include the package name.
For ex:

> /package_name/fxml_file_name.fxml

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your file `second.fxml` is not located in the same folder with `mainFxml.fxml`'s controler java file.

Comment: all the file are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.IOException;

I got it to work by either surrounding the load(getClass... with a try/catch block, or by just importing java.io.IOException.

Enjoy :)